# How To Only Update Scope Values That Have Changed With Mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am updating a large object that holds the application's settings, to trigger each input to save, I am using a combination of ng-blur and ng-change:

```
ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}", ng-change='updateContent();'
```

I am able to update parts of an object with Mongoose with a service like "setting.update"

```
$scope.updateContent = function() {
    setting.update({id:$scope.settings._id}, {
        name: $scope.settings.name,
        tag: $scope.settings.tag,
        hours: $scope.settings.hours,
        address: $scope.settings.address,             
        phone: $scope.settings.phone,
        email: $scope.settings.email
    });
};
```

Because the whole object is fairly large, how can I only update the value that has changed in the controller. Which would equal:

```
$scope.updateContent = function() {
    setting.update({id:$scope.settings._id}, {
        name: $scope.settings.name
    });
};
```

Without repeating the function above thirty times? I will also need to repeat this pattern when updating approximately ten base64 images.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to efficiently pass this information into the function... so I will be handling each input with a function to save it's individual value to a MongoDB.

```
$scope.updateContent = function() {
    setting.update({id:$scope.settings._id}, {
        name: $scope.settings.name
    });
};
```